# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svm_margin_plot'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, svm, ipynb

I am trying to write a code in jupyter and I have this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svm_margin_plot'"

Here is my code:
`from svm_margin_plot import plot_svm_boundary`